# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{2}}=a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{2}}=a+b$, obviously this can just be evaluated by a computer to find $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ but I'm wondering if there's a *relatively* simple algebraic way of calculating it other than using the above equation and $9+6\sqrt{2}=a^2+2ab+b^2$

Comment: You have one equation and two unknowns. Also $a=0$ and $b=\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{2}}$ is a solution (as well as infinitely many others).

Comment: No, $a=\sqrt3$ and $b=\sqrt2$ won't work. $(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2=5+2\sqrt6$ appears to be closest to what you mean.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, I'm just curious because wolfram is able to identify this solution instantly and it is the nicest one imo.

Comment: Another solution is $a=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{6}$ and $b=2\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose instead that $a$ and $b$ are integers such that 
$$\sqrt{9 + 6\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$$
Squaring both sides of the expression yields
$$9 + 6\sqrt{2} = a + b + 2\sqrt{ab}$$
Setting $a + b = 9$ yields
\begin{align*}
6\sqrt{2} & = 2\sqrt{ab}\\
3\sqrt{2} & = \sqrt{ab}\\
\sqrt{18} & = \sqrt{ab}\\
18 & = ab
\end{align*}
This yields the system of equations
\begin{align*}
a + b & = 9\\
ab & = 18
\end{align*}
Substituting $9 - a$ for $b$ in the equation $ab = 18$ yields
\begin{align*}
a(9 - a) & = 18\\
9a - a^2 & = 18\\
0 & = a^2 - 9a + 18\\
0 & = (a - 3)(a - 6)
\end{align*}
Hence, $a = 3$ or $a = 6$.  Use the equation $b = 9 - a$ to solve for $b$ in each case.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

If $$a+b=\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{2}}$$ $$(a+b)^2=9+6\sqrt{2}=3+6+6 \sqrt{2}=3+6+2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{2}=3+6+2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{6}=(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6})^2$$